# Wrong output when formatting diff() in Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to format the `diff()` of my 2 dates using `Carbon` in laravel. Please see my code below.

**View**

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff(auth()->user()->getSubscriptionFor($class)->subscription_ends_at, false)->format('%ddays %hhrs %imins') }}
```

**Data**

subscription_ends_at: `2020-01-27 11:38:11`
subscribed_at: `2019-11-27 11:36:26`

**Output**

> 30days 21hrs 37mins

**Expected Output**

*Greater than 60days*

Comment: You need output the month which is 1 in your case.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I only need days, hours, and mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Carbon` `diff` returns a `DateInterval`, to access the days you can use `days` of `DateInterval` and `a` in `format`.

Replace `format('%ddays %hhrs %imins')` with `format('%adays %hhrs %imins')`

[See all DateInterval formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: Uhm. The ouput now is `30aysdays 21hrs 15mins`.

Comment: Do you have a reference/link with `a`?

Comment: @Jonjie https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: This is perfect! :)